# Adding a insert filename function to a macro

Tags: excel, vba, filenames

I need help with getting the imported filename inserted on a worksheet in excel.  I got this code from someplace online and just want the imported filename to be populated in a cell on a worksheet called "LOGSTAT Report" that already exists in the workbook.

Here is the macro I have

```
Option Explicit

' ************************************************
' Variables For File Open Dialogue Box
' ************************************************
Public strDialogueFileTitle As String
Public strFilt As String
Public intFilterIndex As Integer
Public strCancel As String
Public strWorkbookNameAndPath As String
Public strWorkbookName As String
Public strWorksheetName As String

Public Sub OpenAFileAndCopyData()
Dim wkbMasterWorkbook As Workbook
Dim wksMasterWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim wkbImportedWorkbook As Workbook
Dim wksImportedWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim rngImportCopyRange As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wkbMasterWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
Set wksMasterWorksheet = Sheets("READIsim Output")

' ****************************************************************************
' Set Up Filters For Which Files Should Show In The Open File Dialog Box
' ****************************************************************************
strFilt = "CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv,"

' ****************************************************************************
' Set Up The Prompt In The Dialogue Box
' ****************************************************************************
intFilterIndex = 1
strDialogueFileTitle = "Select The Workbook You Want To Import"

' ****************************************************************************
' Present the Open File Dialogue To The User
' ****************************************************************************
Call OpenFileDialogue

' ****************************************************************************
' Notify The User If No File Was Successfully Opened
' ****************************************************************************
If strCancel = "Y" Then
    MsgBox ("An Open Error Occurred Importing Your File Selection")
    Exit Sub
End If

' ****************************************************************************
' Set Imported Workbook and Worksheet Variables
' ****************************************************************************
Set wkbImportedWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set wksImportedWorksheet = wkbImportedWorkbook.Sheets(1)


' ****************************************************************************
' Choose This Or The Next
' Copy The Data (Paste Special Will Be The Next Example)
' ****************************************************************************
Set rngImportCopyRange = Range(wksImportedWorksheet.Cells(1, 1), Cells(500, 1)).EntireRow
rngImportCopyRange.Copy wksMasterWorksheet.Cells(1, 1)
wkbMasterWorkbook.Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wkbImportedWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

wksMasterWorksheet.Activate
wksMasterWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub OpenFileDialogue()

' ************************************************
' Display a File Open Dialogue Box For The User
' ************************************************
strCancel = "N"
strWorkbookNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (FileFilter:=strFilt, _
     FilterIndex:=intFilterIndex, _
     Title:=strDialogueFileTitle)

' ************************************************
' Exit If No File Selected
' ************************************************
If strWorkbookNameAndPath = "" Then
    MsgBox ("No Filename Selected")
    strCancel = "Y"
    Exit Sub
ElseIf strWorkbookNameAndPath = "False" Then
    MsgBox ("You Clicked The Cancel Button")
    strCancel = "Y"
    Exit Sub
End If

' ******************************************************
' Now That You Have The User Selected File Name, Open It
' ******************************************************
Workbooks.Open strWorkbookNameAndPath

ActiveSheet.Columns("B:AN").NumberFormat = "General"

End Sub
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your 3rd last line of code is:

```
Workbooks.Open strWorkbookNameAndPath
```

After this line you might add

```
MsgBox strWorkbookNameAndPath
```

to get a msgBox with the name of the file you have opened.

You might use

```
Debug.Print strWorkbookNameAndPath
```

to see the name of the opened file in the immediate window (Ctrl G in VBE).

With the command

```
Worksheets("LOGSTAT Report").Range("A1").Value = strWorkbookNameAndPath
```

the filename is inserted in the cell "A1" on the worksheet "LOGSTAT Report".

Comment: I am able to get the message box that shows the file name, but then it gives me issues with the following command.

Comment: It seems as though it is looking for the LOGSTAT Report Worksheet in the file I am importing rather than the Workbook that I am importing the info into which is where I want the filename and all to appear.